# Unable to search with a particular field mentioned in schema.xml

Tags: solr

The following is my schema.xml

```
<field name="preset_id" indexed="true" type="long"/>
<field name="ep_user_id" indexed=" true" type="long" required="false"/>
<field name="preset_name" indexed="true" type="string"/>
<field name="origin" indexed="true" type="string"/>
<uniqueKey>preset_id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>preset_name</defaultSearchField>
```

am using the standard search handler

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
<!-- default values for query parameters -->
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <!--
  <int name="rows">10</int>
  <str name="fl">*</str>
  <str name="version">2.1</str>
  -->
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

with the query **select/?q=*at*+AND+origin%3ASingapore&rows=100** my response is

```
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">330</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="version">2.2</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
<str name="q">*at* AND origin:Singapore</str>
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="indent">on</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="19" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="ep_user_id">114048</str>
<str name="origin">Singapore</str>
<long name="preset_id">1666</long>
<str name="preset_name">Watch</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="ep_user_id">114053</str>
<str name="origin">Singapore</str>
<long name="preset_id">1752</long>
<str name="preset_name">Watch</str>
</doc>
....
```

But if i query with the query string as **/select/?q=*at*+AND+ep_user_id%3A14048&&rows=100**

```
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">156</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="version">2.2</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
<str name="q">*at* AND ep_user_id:14048</str>
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="indent">on</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

I am not able to filter the results based on ep_user_id but am successful with origin. Need assistance to resolve this..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe check the space in the schema `indexed=" true"`